# Rails querying many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quick question here. Given the following [example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) many-to-many relationship, how would I query the Physician table for appointments they have today?

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

On the Physician model I have the following:

```
scope :for, -> (name) { find_by_name(name: name) }
# I need a hand here, the join I assumed would work didn't seem to filter properly.
# scope :appointments_today, -> { joins(:appointment).where("appointments.appointment_date = ?", Date.today) }
scope :appointments_today, -> { ??? }
```

I'd like to chain queries on the controller as such:

```
data = Physician.for("test").appointments_today
```

Comment: What type is the `appointment_date`?

Comment: In the example it's a datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want a list of `Physician` records that have an appointment scheduled for today, or do you want a list of `Appointment` records that are for a specific physician and are scheduled for today?

Physicians that have an appointment today:

```
Physician.
  joins(:appointments).
  where(
    name: "test",
    appointments: {
      appointment_date: (Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
    }
  )
```

Appointments for a physician that are today:

```
Appointment.
  joins(:physician).
  where(
    appointment_date: (Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day),
    physicians: { name: "test" }
  )
```

As scopes, you can do physicians that have an appointment today:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :named, -> (name) { where(name: name) }
  scope :with_appointments_on, -> (date) { joins(:appointments).where(appointments: { appointment_date: (date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day) })}
end

Physician.named("test").with_appointments_on(Date.today)
```

Or appointments for a physician that are today:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :on_date, -> (date) { where(appointment_date: (date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day)) }
end

Physician.find_by_name("test").appointments.on_date(Date.today)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch a list of appointments, the logic should go in the `Appointment` model:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient

  scope :for_today, -> { where('appointments.appointment_date >= ? AND appointments.appointment_date < ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day) }

  scope :for_physician, -> (name) { joins(:physician).where(physicians: {name: name}) }
end
```

And the you can find the appointments by:

`data = Appointment.for_today.for_physician("test")`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the commented out example quickly. Even when I compared dates the way you did, the chaining of the query was not working. It would get all appointments for "test" but not for today. It wasn't filtering for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
scope :for, -> (name) { where(name: name) }
```

Next, you have to add plural into `appointments`

```
scope :appointments_today, -> { joins(:appointments).where("appointments.appointment_date = ?", Date.today) }
```

I hope this help you.